# .NET Core 3.1 app don't use cookie shared from MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

I have two apps, the first one (192.168.100.12:9001) is created with .NET Framework ASP.NET MVC 5 and is for logging into my system. The second one (192.168.100.12:9002) is a Web Api created with .NET Core 3.1 .
I want to authorize user in webapi (second app) only if he logged into my system by the first app early.

According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I've edited both projects in this way:

*App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs*

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                                                                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                                                                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) =>
                                                                        user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },
        TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(new DataProtectorShim(
            DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\MyApp\Client\common-key-rings"), (builder) => {
                builder.SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");
            })
            .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                             CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, "v2"))),
        CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
    });

    System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name";
}
```

*Models/IdentityModels.cs*

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

It's seems to work because I can find a `.AspNet.SharedCookie` cookie in browser console after logged in the first app.

Now, I need to read this cookie in my .NET Core WebApi:

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\MyApp\Client\common-key-rings"))
            .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");
   
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
            // Change the options as needed
                options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "clientapp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientapp";
            spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, when I hit the sample WeatherForecastController get method user is not logged: `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `False`, `User.Identity.Name` is `null`, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false` too. But `Request.Cookies` contains my `.AspNet.SharedCookie` cookie, and I can find it in browser console too. What I'm missing?

Comment: You're not adding identity to your api app, only the cookie parts. You need to add it in your api app.

Comment: I've created a new, fresh, .NET Core project with Identity Authorization and the effect is same.